# Implementing ICompositeUserType for immutable type

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have an immutable Money type (ammount and currency) and I'm copying an example I saw [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/opiesblog/archive/2006/08/05/87218.aspx).

They implement the deep copy like so:

```
public object DeepCopy(object value)
{
    return new Money(((Money) value).Amount, ((Money) value).Currency);
}
```

Which is pointless and inefficient for immutables. But as I don't know the NHibernate libs inside out, I want to know if it is nessasary, and if it's safe to do this:

```
public object DeepCopy(object value)
{
    return value;
}
```

The only difference I can foresee is if somewhere in NHibernate they are relying on `object`'s `!=` operator returning `true`. But that would be nasty, so I doubt that's going on, but I'd like confirmation.

Also, please note my money is a `class`, not a `struct`.

Comment: Well you could have `return (Money)value;` which should give you a copy too with (a bit) less casting/work. At the very least, you could probably whip up a contrived test to see if NHibernate cares (I don't think it would, but I haven't used its latest versions)

Comment: @ChrisSinclair a cast won't give me a copy. All that will do is throw up if `value` is not a `Money`.

Comment: It's a `struct`, performing the cast and returning it will create a copy. (note that your current implementation will also throw an exception if `value` is not a `Money`)

Comment: @ChrisSinclair I see, his is a struct, I missed that **but** even in that case `return value` creates a copy of value. Structs are always passed by value.

Comment: `[TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        struct Money { }

        public object JustPassThrough(object obj)
        {
            return obj;
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void Struct_is_copied_on_return()
        {
            var money = new Money();
            var passed = JustPassThrough(money);
            Assert.AreNotSame(money, passed);
        }
    }`

Comment: Actually, it's the passing _into_ of `JustPassThrough` that creates the copy in this case. I suggested to do the cast/return in `DeepCopy` if only because it's already passing in `object` thus the `DeepCopy` method would perform _no copying at all_ which I assume would be unexpected. I don't know if NHibernate would ever functionally create the copy otherwise. I suspect that it will likely create a copy _somewhere_ simply because it's a struct. This all seems like overkill for NHibernate to cache a `struct` that's _immutable_ no less. I suggest you try testing the caching mechanism regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DeepCopy is there to have a copy for change tracking which is pointless for immutable types so your implementation is typical for all immutable types

```
public bool IsMutable
{
    get { return false; }
}

public object DeepCopy(object value)
{
    return value;
}
```